# my browser internet is slow on making connections

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I see plenty of "waiting for yy.com" for example after I open up `www.google.com` I see `waiting for plus.google.com` after opening up `yahoo.com` I see in status bar `waitnig for yahoo.com` plenty of time.
is anything going on?

I tried `tracepath` for example and i get this:

```
$ tracepath www.google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  10.0.0.138                                            1.266ms 
 1:  10.0.0.138                                            5.865ms 
 2:  10.0.0.138                                           13.972ms pmtu 1492
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
^C
LAP:~$
```

i'm not sure whats going on with my internet... what should i check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your internet speed in throttled down by your ISP. Also try changing your DNS to open ones like 8.8.8.8